# How to Listen for Token Refreshes Properly in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

We have a handler registered to save our JWT token to local storage (we're using React):

```
firebaseAuth.onIdTokenChanged((user) => {  
   user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {  
      localStorage.setItem('token', idToken);  
   }
}
```

We then read from local storage in other places to make API calls. The desired behavior would be that this would keep the user logged in unless their account is revoked.

However, for some reason, it seems as though after the initial JWT token expires, the handler either doesn't run or doesn't read the new token properly and thus the user remains in a weird half logged-in, half logged out state.

We're using onIdTokenChanged, so it seems as though it should run when a token refresh needs to happen. Are we doing something wrong?

Also, testing has been a pain because we need to wait an hour for the token refresh to trigger. Is there any easier way to force a new token? Seeing other Stack Overflow posts, seems like no, but if there is it would make debuggging easier.